# Batch changing materials in a scene

Tags: materials, shaders

[image]

I would like to change all materials so that the base color "multiply" is actually set as an image texture that uses the texture set on Color1. I have a huge amount of materials and will take hours to change them all by hand. How can i do this?

[image]

This is the result i want.

Comment: Often one can change several objects parameters at once by using the Alt key.   However I'm not sure this is possible with material node inputs.  You may have to look at Python scripting, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Having some fun with python today, I created a script that would add an image texture shader node (actually a node *group* containing the image texture) to any Material that has a Principled BSDF with an unconnected *Base Color* input.

If you're comfortable with python you can play around to perhaps only look at materials in objects in certain collections, or only selected objects, etc.

```
import bpy

###
###  add the existing group node 'ImageNodeGroup' to any Material node that has an un connected Base Color'input
###
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    if 'NoNo' in m.name:  # example skip criteria
        continue
    if m.node_tree != None:  # some materials may not have a shader node tree
        hasImageNodeGroup = False
        principledBSDF = None
        for n in m.node_tree.nodes:
            if n.type=='GROUP' and n.node_tree!=None:
                if n.node_tree.name == 'ImageNodeGroup':  # I renamed this to this name
                    print(m.name, 'has', n.node_tree.name, n.bl_idname )
                    hasImageNodeGroup = True
            if n.name == 'Principled BSDF':
                if len(n.inputs['Base Color'].links)==0: # unconnected: candidate
                    principledBSDF = n
        if (principledBSDF!=None and not hasImageNodeGroup):
            # add ImageNodeGroup to color input of hasPrincipledBSDF
            print( 'adding ImageNodeGroup to', m.name )
            sng = m.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')  # create a new group node for this material
            sng.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[ 'ImageNodeGroup' ] # have it use the group with the image texture
            m.node_tree.links.new( principledBSDF.inputs['Base Color'], sng.outputs['Color']) # link node input and output of interest
```

[image]

Here my example:  [image] where you can do a Text::Run_Script in the script pane and check the materials for correct outcome.